# Open Graph stories only show up in activity log

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our game was approved (Open Graph stories, publish_actions permission etc) by Facebook, however when users post Open Graph stories they only show up in activity log and don't show up on Timeline at all. Even stories with explicit sharing property. Neither regular user nor test users\admins have them showing up in Timeline. The game is already out of a "sandbox" mode. 
Our platform is Web-FB Canvas.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# cutecats_game: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/cutecats_game#">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="117626198575574">
    <meta property="og:type" content="cutecats_game:quest">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://fbcats.integra-games.com//mcats/og.story.php?img=quest_complete.jpg&title=New%20Amazing%20Quest!&desc=Complete%20amazing%20quests%20and%20receive%20helpful%20rewards!%20Will%20you%20complete%20this%20epic%20quest?&ref=st_quest&explicitly=true&objectType=quest">
    <meta property="og:title" content="New Amazing Quest!">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Complete amazing quests and receive helpful rewards! Will you complete this epic quest?"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://fbcats.integra-games.com/mcats/story/quest_complete.jpg">
 <meta property="fb:explicitly_shared" content="true">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://apps.facebook.com/cutecats_game/?ref=st_quest"/>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Links to FB on this object are passed by this method https://graph.facebook.com/me/cutecats_game:complete

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: FB changed the priority of OpenGraph stories in the newsfeed a while ago AFAIK. There is no way to explicitly guarantee that such a story appears.

Comment: Has your app been through review and approved by Facebook for the additional capability, expicitly_shared? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#capabilities